# Calling class function from program.cs at runtimes in .net 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

In previous core version, if there is need to pass dependency while calling any function i used to pass parameter in configure method and use same value to pass as parameter while calling function.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, 
UserManager<IdentityUser> usermanager, RoleManager<IdentityRole rolemanager) 
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    SeedData.Seed(userManager, roleManager);

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
}
```

But in .Net 6 same flow cannot be applied due to only program.cs file. I tried to call function from program.cs file but i get : 'Cannot resolve scoped service 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]' from root provider.'

Program.cs File

```
using LeaveManagement;
using LeaveManagement.Data;
using LeaveManagement.Interfaces;
using LeaveManagement.Mapper;
using LeaveManagement.Repositories;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));


builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Maps));

builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();


var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

var userManager = app.Services.GetRequiredService<UserManager<IdentityUser>>();
var roleManager = app.Services.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
SeedData.Seed(userManager, roleManager);

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

I find the above solution working for some case but it is not working for me.

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to get the object

```cs
var usermanager = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<UserManager<IdentityUser>>();
```

It can help (of cause, you only call it AFTER adding the services). But you can consider another way to achieve your work. Because by calling `BuildServiceProvider`, the framework can't guarantee the singleton scope.

Comment: In .net 6.0, app.Services doesnot have any definition of BuildServiceProvider(). or i am making mistake how do i add services?

Comment: Seem you have to install the package https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection Normally, this package is build-in in your project. (Sorry if I was wrong)